# Who adds interrupt vector table to process virtual address space?

Tags: assembly, linker, operating-system, emulation, loader

Is loading of IV table in virtual address space assembly, linker or loader job? 
Also which part of OS reserve space for stack and heap in general?

Comment: What, exactly, are you talking about? On x86, the Interrupt Vector Table (IVT) contains the addresses of all 256 of the interrupt handlers used in real mode. It is loaded by the ROM BIOS and is typically located at `0000:0000h`. This location can be changed by moving the table using the `LIDT` instruction, but this is rarely done. Is this what you're talking about? This is not maintained per-process. Can you provide some more context for your question?

Comment: What architecture are you talking about?

Comment: well assembly would have nothing to do with it that is just a language. it also depends on the system design (which in this case is mostly the software/operating system design) so there is no one answer you would have to ask these (separate) questions for a very specific platform, operating system and version and set of tools.

Answer (score 0):

The interrupt vector is system wide and resides in the system are of the address space shared by all processes. Is is generally set up by the system loader. However, the PeeCee bios has a built in interrupt vector that is normally replaced by operating system.

> Also which part of OS reserve space for stack and heap in general?

The stack and heap are just memory. There are kernel mode heaps and stacks that exist in the system space. The heap is created by the application. The initial stack is usually defined by the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, the BIOS normally loads the IVT so it can handle real mode interrupts.